# Moving a square across the screen and out the other side

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I need to move a square across the screen. When it gets to the end, it should appear again at the startpoint in a continous loop.

I can do this using setInterval. But I would like to call the function using requestAnimationFrame. Currently the square keeps going in one direction and off the screen. I am using jquery for my code.

```
  let block = document.getElementById('mydiv');
  let startPos = 0;
  function moveStone(timestamp){
    startPos += 5;
    block.style.left = startPos + 'px';
    requestAnimationFrame(moveStone);
  }`enter code here`
  requestAnimationFrame(moveStone);
```

I expect the square to reappear at the start point, but it is going on and on in one direction.

Comment: Why do you expect the square to reappear at the start point? You keep increasing the `startPos`. Share the `setInterval`-based code you have that works. That would make adapting it to use `requestAnimationFrame` easier. (It's always easier to start from something that works.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping in code can be achieved a number of ways. Here's a modulus approach (warning! untested!);

```
  let block = document.getElementById('mydiv');
  let startPos = 0;
  const maxPos = 100;
  function moveStone(timestamp){
    startPos += 5;
    block.style.left = (startPos % maxPos) + 'px';
    requestAnimationFrame(moveStone);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(moveStone);
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfect. I modified the maxPos = screenwidth. The screen is longer than 700px.

Comment: Thank you, always happy to help, but I'm also a badge hunter working on my JS badge :)